# Cq5 dispatcher is it must or optional

Tags: aem

We are getting lot of problems with dispatcher, As per CQ5 documentation dispatcher is cache and/or load balancing tool, so as per my analysis we can go with out dispatcher also,I am correct? I want to integrate Squid or varnish web cache with my apache, so want get shutdown  the dispatcher, will it be a good option

Any views/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly possible to run a website without the Dispatcher in front. Your options would then seem to come down to:

- No caching
- Implementing a cache in front of the Publish instance (e.q. Squid/Varnish, as you mentioned; configuration required)
- Integrate a caching solution in Java that you can apply to parts of your templates/components individually (development required)

Also, you'd need to check with Adobe what level of support they'd give you for any of the above solutions before undertaking them. If you like, you could post specific questions to SO around the problems you're facing with the Dispatcher and you may get some resolutions too.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Dispatcher is also a security layer to close access to some parts of the repository, like /apps. If another (or no) caching layer is used, then similar security rules must be configured there.

Answer (score 1):

I was told that you should use dispatcher servers for your publish instance, because it really helps the loading times. There also was a documentation with a table showing how much it affects the performance depending on the number of documents served.

To avoid caching problems, you can specify files, folders or file types which should never be cached. You can also specify caching behaviour in the source code of the pages. Also, making changes to content on your author instance triggers a flush on the dispatcher for the affected content, to make sure that no cached old version is beeing served.

Last but not least using an apache server also allows you to handle virtual hosts and rewrite rules easily.

Answer (score -1):

Its a must.

If you are getting problems with dispatcher, this could be a sign that you are using the wrong platform for your development needs. Seeing as you are needing to revert to technologies that are not needed for AEM.

Comment: I don't have the rep to down vote, so I'll comment -1 instead.  It is most certainly not a must.

Comment: you don't have to take my word for it and you can workaround the architecture all you wan't, if the OP has a problem he should just describe it, so that its clear what it actually is... if OP has discovered a bug hats-of if not, otherwise wise I am happy to help solve his usage pattern...